# CodeRef macro not working in wiki

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29#preview
So on this page, the CodeRef macro didn't work, and I've even tried to copy-paste the corresponding section in

http://wiki.ros.org/WritingTutorials#preview

```
==== CodeRef ====
In a tutorial, you want to reference a code block that you have created earlier in the tutorial you can use `CodeRef`. 
{{{start
{{{
#!cplusplus block=blockname
code....
is super 
and awesome
}}}
start}}}

You can then use the `CodeRef` macro to refer to it
{{{
<<CodeRef(blockname,1,2)>>
}}}

This then looks like:

<<CodeRef(blockname,1,2)>>
```

the exact same section which works on the "writing tutorials" page didn't work on "writing a tf listener" page.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182961/coderef-macro-not-working-in-wiki/) by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2014-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at [the change you (assumed by the user name) made](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29?action=diff&rev1=63&rev2=64), I guess you've figured it out somehow by yourself; As [the tutorial you referred to](http://wiki.ros.org/WritingTutorials#CodeRef) points out:

```
Note that #!cplusplus or #!python line needs to be in a new line (ie. new line after three beginning parenthesises).
```

it seems that a new line is required with `CodeRef`, which you did in your commit.

---

Update 7/14/2014) Anyways, for referring to codes on github, it looks like `GetCode` [replaces CodeRef macro](http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29?action=diff&rev2=66&rev1=64).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on 2014-07-11**:
I did make a new line for that code, but it seems that might not be the case (or just the website take effect with a delay, not in real time) as the page remains the same after I did the change. and when I come back a day later, everything is fine.